# Function print value but not return

Tags: php, ratchet

I am trying to configure the Binary.com API, but with some difficulties.
I need to get the message back, but that's not the right way.

In function, if I ask to return the array, it does not return. But if I send a print, the result is displayed on the screen.

See:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$connector = new \Ratchet\Client\Connector($loop);

$GLOBALS['app_id'] = XXX;

class Bot {

    public static function authorize($loop, $connector, $token, $ret = null) {
        if (!is_array($ret)) {
            $connector('wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=' . $GLOBALS['app_id'])->then(function ($conn) use ($loop, $token) {

                $conn->send("{\"authorize\": \"" . $token . "\"}");

                $conn->on('message', function (\Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\MessageInterface $msg) use ($conn) {
                    $conn->close();
                    Bot::authorize(null, null, json_decode($msg, true));
                });
            }, function ($e) {
                Bot::authorize(null, null, $e->getMessage());
                $loop->stop();
            });
            $loop->run();
        }
        print_r($ret); //Data is displayed on screen
        return $ret;
    }

}

$bot = Bot::authorize($loop, $connector, 'a1-tokenxxx');

print_r($bot); //Data is not displayed on screen
```

See the comments.
Why is this happening?

What is the correct way to return promise data?

Comment: The `authorize()` method does not know varible `$loop`, but calls `stop()` on it. If You have error messages disabled, this may fail silently with fatal error.

Comment: I agree with @RomanHocke. Or the `$res` may have `null` value. `print_r` won't show `null`. use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` to debug.

Comment: @RomanHocke @Banujan Balendrakumar Even passing `$loop` in `Bot::authorize ($loop, $connector, 'a1-tokenxxx')`, the problem continues.
Error logging is enabled and nothing is displayed on the screen.

Comment: The problem is that the correct print is made by a recursive call to authorize, but you never return that value from the recursive call. And even if you did, it would return it to an asynchronous context, not to your main call of authorize, which anyway would not be possible because that function can only return synchronously, so it is like wanting to get a value *now* that is only available in the *future*. You need to embrace the asynchronous pattern and not expect things to return synchronously.

Comment: Please don't add [ arbitrary things ] to your title or code. It's distracting and unhelpful.